# Why is loading data done enable WAL need long time?

Tags: ignite

I disable WAL before loading data and I enable WAL after loading data and it takes a long time, I need to know what ignite doing?

Answer (score 0):

When you enable WAL, Ignite just invokes [checkpoint](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/persistence-checkpointing) and writes everything that it has in the checkpoint buffer to the disk.

Comment: Usually load  1400w data and it takes 3-4 minutes to enable WAL is that normal?

Comment: what does it mean "1400w data"?

Comment: 14 million data

Comment: Actually, it depends on a lot of things, but if you have slow HDD(and not a SSD), complex and big objects, then it probably could be the case